# How to ping sub devices under different network ports when using a network bridge in Linux?

Tags: linux

How to ping sub devices under different network ports when using a network bridge in Linux?
I have built a remote virtual network using N2N technology, and there is also a network port on my gateway that connects to other devices. Below is the topology diagram：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYvpY.png)
The function I want to implement is shown in the figure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaXz9.png)

I know I can ping and forward without using a bridge, but now I need to use a bridge because I need to receive MAC addresses. I want to use the bridge as a hub.
Here are my commands for building a bridge:
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
ifconfig edge0 0.0.0.0
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 edge0
ip link set br0 up
ip a a 192.168.1.20/24 dev br0

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

At this point, I need to confirm that the IP and MAC addresses of the bridge are the IP and MAC of the original edge0 (remote virtual network card), otherwise my PC cannot ping.
At this point, I need to confirm that the IP and MAC addresses of the bridge are the IP and MAC of the original edge0 (remote virtual network card), otherwise my PC cannot ping